# SQL Server : primary key violation on occasion despite prior deletion

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a procedure that is supposed to replace an entry in my table by first deleting it based on an id and then inserting it with new values.
It looks like this, plus additional values used for the insert statement that I have left out.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DemoProc]
    @id BIGINT,
    ...
AS
    IF EXISTS (SELECT id FROM demoTable WHERE id = @id)
        DELETE demoTable 
        WHERE id = @id

    INSERT INTO demoTable (id, ...) 
    VALUES (@id, ...)

    RETURN 0
```

Now every now and again, I'm getting an error log that alerts me of a primary key violation that originates from this procedure. I also end up with the entry not being inserted at all. Any ideas?

Comment: You have a race condition when the proc is executed with the same @id by different threads. Both threads will attempt the delete (only one will actually delete a row) and then one of the threads will get a PK violation with the unconditional insert.

Comment: @DanGuzman I forgot to mention that I end up with no inserted entry at all. With your explanation however, it should still be inserted one way or another, correct?

Comment: I would expect one of the inserts to succeed and the others to fail with a PK error.

Comment: `IF EXISTS (<this row>) DELETE <this row>;` -> why not just `DELETE <this row>;`? What do you get from looking for `<this row>` twice? Moreover, why delete the row and then insert a new one when you could simply _update_ it with the new values?

Comment: @AaronBertrand good question, I did not create this procedure, just trying to fix the error it is causing. I will change it to update as well as adding a transaction so that hopefully if this happens in the future, we are not left with no records at all